# Como referenciar mais de um atributo ID utilizando a API jpa?

Tags: java, jpa, padrão-dao

A minha dúvida é se eu posso utilizar a anotação `@ID` várias vezes seguidas, se isso é possível ou se há outra forma de referenciar atributos do tipo **ID** após o primeiro.

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "t_Turma")
class Turma {
    @Id
    private int id_Professor;
    @Column(name = id_Disciplina)
    private int id_Disciplina;
    @Column(name = id_Quadrimestre)
    private int id_Quadrimestre;
    @Column
    private int id_Turma;
    @Column
    private String plano;

    public int getId_Turma(){
        return this.id_Turma;
        }
    public void setId_Turma(int id_Turma){
        this.id_Turma = id_Turma;
        }
    public String getPlano(){
        return this.plano;
    }
    public void setPlano(String plano){
        this.plano = plano;
    }
}
```

Comment: Se eu entendi bem. Esses ids em uma mesma entidade são chaves estrangeiras? Caso seja, você precisa fazer os relacionamentos com as tags Many to Many, One to Many e One to One. Na documentação do JPA você encontrará essas informações detalhadas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou separar minha resposta em partes, respondendo a sua pergunta:

**Sim**, é possível ter mais de uma anotação `@Id` em sua classe, **porém**, isso é uma facilidade que o Hibernate proporciona e **não está dentro da especificação do JPA**.

Caso você utilize apenas JPA, então isso **não** funcionará.

Agora irei explicar como fazer de formas padrões JPA

*Talk is cheap, show me the code! - Linus Torvalds*

### Utilizando [@IdClass](https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/IdClass)

Essa abordagem consiste em criar uma classe contendo os campos que formam os identificadores da sua entidade, e referenciar esta classe na anotação `@IdClass`:

```
public class ProjetoId {
    Long departamentoId;
    Long projetoId;
}

@Entity 
@IdClass(ProjetoId.class)
public class Projeto {

    @Id 
    private Long departamentoId;

    @Id 
    private Long projetoId;

     ...
}
```

### Utilizando [@EmbeddedId](https://www.objectdb.com/api/java/jpa/EmbeddedId)

Essa abordagem consiste em incluir uma classe que representa as chaves da entidade diretamente como um atributo da classe:

```
@Embeddable
public class ProjetoId {
    Long departamentoId;
    Long projetoId;
}

@Entity 
public class Projeto {

    @EmbeddedId 
    private ProjetoId id;

     ...
}
```

Isso provê uma boa chance de reutilização do código, além de deixar a classe mais limpa.

### Utilizando múltiplos @Id

Como mencionei antes, essa abordagem só funciona caso você estiver utilizando **Hibernate**, você pode conferir a documentação dizendo isso [aqui](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e4819), e eu também posso colocar a citação:

> 5.1.2.1.2. Multiple id properties without identifier type
>
> Another, arguably more natural, approach is to place @Id on multiple properties
>   of your entity. **This approach is only supported by Hibernate (not JPA
>   compliant)** but does not require an extra embeddable component.

Com isso você pode simplesmente declarar vários ids:

```
@Entity 
public class Projeto {

    @Id 
    private Long departamentoId;

    @Id 
    private Long projetoId;

     ...
}
```

Vou deixar aqui também o [link da especificação do JPA](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/entity/id) para darem uma olhada.

Comment: Obrigada! Ficou muito bem explicado :)

Comment: @Juliana Não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita :)