# Como persistir e consultar entidades embeddable que não tem relacionamento bidirecional usando JPARepository

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data

Usando como exemplo uma aplicação de reserva de hoteis, tenho algo como

```
public class Reserva{ 
    ...
  @CollectionTable(name = "custo_extras", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "reserva_id"))
private List<CustoExtra> custosExtras;
   ...
}


@Embeddable
public class CustoExtra{

  private BigDecimal valor;
  private String descricao;

  ...
}
```

e um repository de custo extra

```
public interface ICustoExtraRepository extends JpaRepository<CustoExtra, Integer>
```

minha questão é, como eu consigo consultar todos os custos extras de uma dada reserva, ou persistir um custo extra de uma reserva, visto que eu não tenho um atributo de reserva na minha classe de custo extra, o que me impossibilitar de fazer um método no repository como

```
List<CustoExtra> findAllByReserva(Reserva reserva);
```

Comment: Você tem que fazer a consulta sempre na entidade ( no caso a `Reserva` ), não na `CustoExtra`. Quando se utiliza `@Embeddable` você está dizendo que a sua entidade possui aquela estrutura. Caso você queira consultar uma entidade que se chame `CustoExtra`, a associação deve ser feita por meio de chave estrangeira

Comment: Respondi uma pergunta um tempo atrás explicando esses conceitos de `@Embeddable` e `@Embedded`, [confira aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/388900/como-referenciar-mais-de-um-atributo-id-utilizando-a-api-jpa/389067#389067)